# How to display something after a user input (submit) ? > HAML + RubyOnRails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

So im quite new to Ruby. I already have some HTML/HAML experience, now I want to do a simple Website with this: A input field and a submit button.

If the user input is < 10 it should display some picture, if its > 10, it should display a other picture. This is what I've done so far:

[image]

**What should I do now to proccess the user input ? I just can't figure out.**

Answer (score 1):

In this case, where you are not doing any server side processing, you should use JavaScript.

Just check value of the input field and do your logic from there.

```
$('form').on('submit',function(){
  if ($('#Input1').val() < 10) {
    $("#my_image").attr("src","first.jpg");
  } 
  else {
    $("#my_image").attr("src","second.jpg");
  }
})
```

Comment: @Pingu can you past your haml here

Comment: I agree with this approach since you don't need anything to be done server side. You should though compare the length of the value, not the value itself.

Comment: @LazarusLazaridis well, the problem is, if I paste some JS code in my application.html.haml file, the displayed page is just blank. Just white blank. And yes, I used the :javascript filter. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @Pingu It might be HAML syntax issue. What happens if you convert your layout to application.html.erb instead?

Comment: @LazarusLazaridis Same problem. The JS just don't display.

Answer (score 0):

Your form syntax is incorrect, it missing the controller action. It should be like this:

```
= form_for controller_method, :html => { :class => "form-horizontal" }
```

Comment: now using this you can access the value of your input field inside the controller action using params[:name].

Comment: Alright, what exactly should I put in for "controller_method" ? Sorry for n00b question :/

Comment: @Pingu do you want to bring those images from backend, i mean are the dynamic?

Comment: @anant: It doesn't matter for me  "where they come from", like from a database or from a web url.

Comment: Then i guess it would be easy for you to do it using javascript

Comment: you can simply change image source 
`$("#my_image").attr("src","second.jpg");`

Comment: Yeah, I think that will be the best solution. Thanks.

Comment: Well, one mor question, if I simply put some javascript in the application.html.haml, then it just won't display the JS. Is there anything I can do so it displays the JS properly ?

Comment: how are you putting up the js code something like this
`:javascript
    $(document).ready( function() {
      $('body').addClass( 'test' );
    } );`

Comment: Yeah, like this. Whatever JS code I enter, it always leads to a blank page.

Comment: I think you might have missed something can you try simple converting your  html to haml using http://html2haml.herokuapp.com/ so this will give you correct syntax for your javascript inside view